# Ubuntu on Surface Pro 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, surface

Last night I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS alongside Windows 10 on my Surface Pro 4 for programming. I did all that with the help of an external keyboard and mouse because Surface keyboard and touchpad don't work. And the touchscreen doesn't work as well, is it possible to get it working?